# Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick, opensearch

Having switched from Elasticsearch to Opensearch, my application now fails to run a simple query with:

> "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require
> per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these
> operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field
> instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [status] in order to
> load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can
> use significant memory."

There's a question concerning the same error at [Searchkick / Elasticsearch Error: Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [name]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67259064/searchkick-elasticsearch-error-please-use-a-keyword-field-instead-alternativ), but there the problem was only affecting tests and I only get the problem (so far) in development mode.

Here's the query being run:

```
::Record.search(q ? q : "*",
                where: where_clause,
                fields: fields,
                match: :word_middle,
                per_page: max_per_page(per_page) || 30,
                page: page || 1,
                order: sort_clause,
                aggs: aggs,
                misspellings: {below: 5}
```

If I take out aggs then the search is fine, but they're essential for the application. Removing `:status` from the list of aggregation fields causes the error to name the next field in the array as the problem. So, I presumably need to specify the correct type for each field used in aggregations. But how?

The Searchkick docs suggest this example under "Advanced Mapping" (https://github.com/ankane/searchkick):

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick mappings: {
    properties: {
      name: {type: "keyword"}
    }
  }
end
```

So, I tried this:

```
# in models/Record.rb
mapping_properties = {}
aggregation_fields.each do |af|
  mapping_properties[af] = { type: 'keyword' }
end
searchkick mappings: {
             properties: mapping_properties
          }
```

But, the same problem persists. I also tried something similar to that shown in the linked post, e.g.

```
mappings: {
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: "text",
          fielddata: true,
          fields: {
            keyword: {
              type: "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

...but similarly without luck.

Can anyone suggest how this might be fixed?

Comment: Its just related to make your field keyword on which you are doing `aggs`, can you do this from fresh and it should work, might be requirted change isn't applied to your mapping, you can check that using `_mapping` Api of Elasticsearch, OS should have similar api to check mapping of index

Comment: Searchkick is creating the indexes, therefore I need to know how to instruct it to do so in a manner to which Opensearch will not object. How to do that remains rather unclear.

Comment: sorry, I can help with the APis not with code, and ultimately its creating index in Elasticsearch/os which you can easily check with their REST api

Comment: Indeed, the fields are created as type "text" rather than "keyword", as the error message indicates, despite the attempts described above to create them as Opensearch requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not related to using Opensearch. Instead, the method of indexing used caused the indexes to be generated incorrectly.

See: [Searchkick memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334743/searchkick-memory-leak)

Answer (score 18):

The immediate issue was dealt with by changing all the fields used for aggregations, so rather than:

```
aggs = %w(field1 field2 field3 ...)
```

...in the above search query.
I used:

```
aggs = %w(field1.keyword field2.keyword field3.keyword ...)
```

Comment: Yes, as explained in the first comment of mine, you needed the `.keyword`, good that you were using the default mapping, so these are created automatically for you but its not good always :)

Comment: I could not infer that from your comment at all.

Comment: ok, still glad you were able to find the solution 

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Tomcat running with Elastic Search while you delete your index it will trigger this error.

Stop your tomcat, again delete your index and you're good to go.

Hope this helps someone